# Upgrade to Windows 10 fails on Windows 7 / Ubuntu dual boot machine

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, windows-10

My attempts to upgrade my Windows 7 install to Windows 10 consistently fails with `Error 800703ED`. I strongly suspect that this is caused by by dual boot setup. I have inserted info re my disk/grub config below. What do I need to do to make the upgrade work without destroying by dual boot set up. I don't particularly need grub as I can use the bios to choose which os to boot as they are on separate disks.

```
                    Boot Info Script 0.74      [06 February 2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 2eb75a40-a660-4b81-910f-8cb9996282ca root hd1,msdos1 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 2eb75a40-a660-4b81-910f-8cb9996282ca root hd1,msdos1 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free software I use a lot which is [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It allows you to completely customize Windows bootloader.

What I suggest is:

1. Use it to set your bootloader to Windows bootloader (using the "Write MBR" function, in "BCD Deployment")
2. Upgrade to Windows 10
3. Use EasyBCD again to set up a dual boot between Windows and Ubuntu

I have used this software on my laptop to set up a dual boot between Windows 10 and Linux Mint 17, and after fiddling a bit it works like a charm. Only problem is it actually call GRUB to start Linux Mint, so in GRUB param I set a very short wait time (3 seconds).

Also if you use it with Windows 10, I strongly recomend you disable the Metro bootloader beacuse it actually boots Windows, asks you to choose which OS to start and if you choose Linux, it restarts the computer and calls the other OS's bootloader. All that can be done in EasyBCD's settings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you completely I was in the same position a couple weeks ago. It is the dual boot, what I did was physically unplug the sata power and data cables (just to be safe) from the disk containing Grub and in my case a copy of Centos 7, then I allowed Windows 10 to install itself and then after wards plugged the disk back in and everything worked like a charm. I was still able to boot Windows 10 and Centos 7 as well the link in the Grub boot menu on Centos 7 still takes me to Windows 10.

Comment: That's another solution, and it'll work with 99.9% efficiency as long as GRUB and Windows are on two different physical disks. I recommend this solution if you don't want to install any third-party software.

Comment: If I unplug the Linux disk (sdb) I cannot boot Windows.

Comment: @NathanShiraini This is a good idea however there is no need to modify the existing BCD or Gurb keep in mind the Windows boot files that grub references now (Windows 7 State) are going to be in the same place just upgraded to there newer versions(Windows 10 State), also Windows 10 is somewhat smart in this sense it shouldn't upgrade the to the "Metro BCD" coming from Windows 7 unless it sees another Windows install on that hard drive, and even if it does the first boot all he has to do is run this command "bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy" and it will go back.

Comment: Windows 10 will not upgrade if it has no bootloader on its side, it will fail because when it starts installing it has to reboot to update the core system files to there Windows 10 counterparts and if it doesn't see a Windows boot manager it thinks the drive is unbootable and aborts, as it cannot see the Grub boot manager.

Comment: This is where @NathanShiraini's solution would come into play, just as long as Windows has a bootloader on its partition it won't error. I would recommend booting Windows then making sure EasyBCD writes its config to the Windows and does not override Grub because Grub doesn't care Windows 10 or Windows 7 it's all the same to it. The boot the Windows disk via the WBM not grub and proceed to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Then once you get Windows 10 installed you can choose whether you like Windows Boot Manager or Grub. Personally I prefer Grub, but again that's my personal preference and WBM as Pointed out by @NathanShiraini can boot to the linux os.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow Ok, I was under the impression that GRUB was only install on sda and that if I used EasyBCD to install WBM on sda that would make it impossible to boot Linux fra sdb? If that makes sense?

Comment: I think I understand you so hopefully this is helpful. Let's say SDA(Windows) and SDB(Linux) are connected both to the computer. If you boot from SDB you will get Grub and can then choose to boot either Windows(regardless of whether it's 7 or 10 that doesn't matter again it's the same to Grub) or linux. SDB can see the WBM but if you boot from SDB it will go to Grub even if it sees WBM on SDA then if you select the option to go to Windows you will be redirected to WBM which will boot W7 or W10 whatever is there. Now if you choose SDA you will go straight to WBM as it can't see Grub.